# Copyright notice in the binaries of a library

Tags: licensing, copyright, gpl-2

I'm building a library that is based on  a modified version of an already existing source released under the GPLv2 license.

I'm modifying each files of the original project to adapt it to my needs, so I'm adding to each file my copyright notice leaving the one  of the original author.

I'm releasing it under the GPLv2  as well.

My question is related to the compiled binaries and to the copyright notices on it.

.net libraries give you the possibility to add a copyright statement in the information of the library, but should I put only my copyright notice or should I mention the original author too?

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/886/copyright-and-contributing-to-an-open-source-project?rq=1), which the system has helpfully identified as being relevant (and I concur)?

Comment: You will distribute your code as a library and as a condition, in GPL V2 you need to [`Disclose source`](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/gpl-2.0/), so in my opinion, you need to set the copyright notice to yourself in the package metadata, but at the same time include in your package 3rd party notice to the original code.

Comment: Why do you want to use a .NET specific binary field for the copyright notice rather than (or in addition to) adding a notice to the source code?

Comment: So I'm not forced to set the copyright notice in the package metadata???

Comment: @alessio, "forced" I don't think you are. It would be the polite thing to do, however (and costs next to nothing).