# Change copyright author after forking GPL v2 code?

Tags: gpl, copyright, gpl-2

Say I fork the source code [here](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/net-analyzer/iftop/iftop-1.0_pre4-r5.ebuild), modify the code, and finally distribute the source code and the derived work.

Can I change the copyright notice at the top from

```
# Copyright 1999-2022 Gentoo Authors
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
```

to myself like the below?

```
# Copyright 2023 John Doe
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
```

Or I must keep the original line like the below?

```
# Copyright 2023 John Doe
# Copyright 1999-2022 Gentoo Authors
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2
```

Comment: Could you read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/886/458) and let us know if it answers yours?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the notice rather than add your own? The normal best practice is to add your own notice, and to preserve the existing ones. In some cases, preserving the existing notices would not be required, but if you're not sure, it's safer to preserve them.

Comment: The file you've quoted is quite short so I could imagine (or assume) that after you've modified it, that very little of the original would still be present in your version. In other words, you may as well have created your own file from scratch. But that's an assumption -- it depends on what you're trying to do. For example, if you're making your own version of this file but you're changing the list of patches (for example),  then I'd consider that a modification, and in such a case you would need to retain the notices.

Comment: But if you're creating a completely new .ebuild file, however, and you are merely consulting this particular file as a "coding example" of how to write such a file, then it's likely that your version of this file is completely your property, and in such a case you would most likely be free to license it in any way you choose.