# Which license can be used when I want to protect contributions to my program?

Tags: license-recommendation

So, we are trying to write library in java which will make it easier to work with images, etc. 
It's something like university project, so we have 15 people in our team.

We don't want anyone to have power to remove his code from our library after we end our project. 
Let's say Peter wrote 7 classes, but something happens and he wants to remove his contributions from our library and because it's his 7 classes we have to do it.

Which license would prevent such things? Maybe it's Apache License 2.0 or GPL?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a CLA and a CTA?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/860/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cla-and-a-cta)

Comment: A license won't really do what you want, you'll need a CLA/CTA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an irrevocable license, such as [version 3 of the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html). With such a license, barring other termination clauses, the author can't retroactively revoke your rights to use the code.

In some legislations, moral rights might apply too; these could give the author a say in what can be done with his/her code. It would be up to courts to decide though, and the fact that the code was licensed in a certain way would presumably come into consideration regardless of the author's subsequent change of mind (but I am not a lawyer). A copyright assignment might help reduce uncertainty, although legislations with moral rights generally don't allow them to be assigned away.